# CSS transition timing not working for all elements, the words in li and anchor tag do not ease with timing

Tags: html, css, angular, sass

I'm trying to do a transition on a navbar from one color to another color on hover.  The navbar has a list of words in it.  When you hover, during the transition, you can see the area flash on quick (looks like a white color block) around the ul/li/a words, so they are NOT picking up the transition timing.  Everything else in the d-flex div transitions correctly.
On hover, the navbar background color should change to white and the words/text change to black with a .25s transition.  Angular 8.

my code:

```css
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  padding-top: 35px;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  min-height: 22px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
}

.d-flex {
  height: 80px;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: all 0.25s;
}

.d-flex:hover,
.d-flex:hover li,
.d-flex:hover a {
  background-color: white;
  color: black !important;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid no-transition">
    <div class="d-flex">
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" [ngClass]="{'in': !menuCollapsed}" [attr.aria-expanded]="!menuCollapsed">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li *ngFor="let link of navLinks" class="{{link.color}}" [ngClass]="{'active': activeTab === link}">
            <a (onClick)="activateTab(link)" href="{{link.path}}" target="{{link.target}}">{{link.label}}</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pay attention to what selectors and styling you put on each element. the `background` for example should change only on the `d-flex` where it is defined.

answer code:

```css
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  padding: 35px 0 0 0;
  margin: 0 15px;
  min-height: 22px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
}

.d-flex {
  height: 80px;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.d-flex,
a,
li {
  transition: 0.25s;
  color: white;
}

.d-flex:hover.d-flex {
  background-color: white;
  transition: 0.25s;
}

.d-flex:hover li,
.d-flex:hover a {
  color: black;
  transition: 0.25s;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid no-transition">
    <div class="d-flex">
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" [ngClass]="{'in': !menuCollapsed}" [attr.aria-expanded]="!menuCollapsed">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li *ngFor="let link of navLinks" class="{{link.color}}" [ngClass]="{'active': activeTab === link}">
            <a (onClick)="activateTab(link)" href="{{link.path}}" target="{{link.target}}">{{link.label}}</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```